# multiple copies of eclipse in different locations

Tags: eclipse

I want to use eclipse on multiple projects simultaneously located in different workspaces. so I intend to extract the installation archive to different locations and run eclipse.exe in each at the same time.

the question: I am expecting bugs or any kind of unwanted interference?

Comment: eclipse has a lot of bugs also if lauched individually

Comment: At one point, Eclipse stored things like plugins in your home directory, but I think they stopped doing that at some point.

Comment: You don't need multiple eclipse installations to start eclipse multiple times.

Comment: @JBNizet As long as you're working in different workspaces, that is.  Which HazernSug seems to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would only use different instances of eclipse if your projects needs different tooling (plugins) and you don't want to clutter interface installing all tools together (for example you could have one for spring projects, one jboss tooling, one for python, one for android projects), but I would probably still install a couple of tools together.

In most cases using one instance is enough and that's what I use (I just choose a workspace I want to work with on eclipse start, but the other option could be to use -data  in the shortcut to specify the workspace location that should be used).

[You can modify the list of recent workspaces by editing eclipse/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs file]

Having one instance could save you time when you update or install new tools (they will automatically be avaliable with all your workspaces).

One common problem here is sharing the preferences between workspaces. (Preferences are stored per workspace). I use one empty workspace with all my favourite settings as a template and just copy ".metadata" folder to every new workspace I create.